# Executing bidirectional Dijkstra on TIFF image?

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, c++, digital-image-processing, dijkstra

Can anyone indicate an example of how to do this? Link, tutorial etc...
I started a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43953630/how-to-load-a-tiff-image-like-a-graph-in-c-boost) about how to load a TIFF image like a graph nicely answered by @sehe.
But, in this post the image is RGB. Then, after change for my needs(TIFF grayscale) the result is a image spatially displaced...

Real example of raster (was converted to PNG after upload) grayscale with float pixel values and current CRS (Coordinate Reference System) is SIRGAS2000:

[image: This is a example of raster clipped]
From original code posted by @sehe I made some changes:

```
// I modified the type from rbg to grayscale
using Img = boost::gil::gray32f_image_t; 
using Px  = Img::value_type;
Img img;

boost::gil::tiff_read_and_convert_image("raster.tif", img);
auto vw = view(img);
```

Next, I modified this code:

```
        auto calc_color = [&](size_t v) {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << std::hex << std::noshowbase << std::setfill('0');

        //I removed the from[1] and from[2] because is a graycale image
        auto const& from = pixel_sample(vertex(v, graph));
        oss << "#" << std::setw(2) << static_cast<int>(from[0]);

        return oss.str();
    };
```

Now, I am trying to use the boost functions:

- Eager Dijkstra shortest paths
- Crauser et al. Dijkstra shortest paths
- Delta-Stepping shortest paths
- Bellman-Ford Shortest Paths
- And if as possible...Bidirectional Dijkstra

But, I'm newbie in C++... I'm reading the Boost documentation and looking examples using TIFF to better understand it but I have not got it yet. 
Then, how to execute this algorithms and how to hold the correct CRS of TIFF in this case?

Comment: It would be helpful to add a question in the body of your question.

Comment: nicely answered and accepted [here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43958550/5158630).

Comment: Yes @StevenKay!!  I started this discussion on SO. But the image is RGB, and now my image is grayscale and I want to hold the original CRS of image and call the Boost Dijkstra functions...

Comment: What is "hold CRS of image"?

Comment: Ah sorry @sehe! The GEOTIFF image have spatial informations and CRS (Coordinate Reference System)  is one of them. So, when I execute the algorithm the output TIFF image (verification.tif) loses this information. I want to keep this.

Comment: I'm not sure. You can run all the algos, and saving the verification image or .dot graph are completely unnecessary steps. CRS will be preserved in the source because it's not modified.